# I get a 0 Byte file when I upload to S3

Tags: python, flask, amazon-s3, boto3

When I programatically upload a file to my S3 Bucket I end up with a 0 Byte file but the name of the file and the folder is good.

```
myfile = request.files["myfile"]
myfile.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)

s3.upload_fileobj(
                    myfile,
                    MY_BUCKET_NAME,
                    folder_name + "/" + my_filename,
                    ExtraArgs={
                       "ContentType": myfile.content_type
                    }
                )
```

Everything seems to work as I have no error and the file is registered at the expected location but its size is 0 B. I am using postman to upload the file.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Try removing `myfile.seek(0)`

Comment: Wow thanks. It worked. I didn't write this code myself and it was working fine in the past with the `myfile.seek(0)` . I don't know what happened since then. Anyway thanks you solved my problem !

Comment: `myfile.seek(0)` goes to the start of the file while `myfile.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)` goes to the end of the file